# Excel VBA - Bypass my own code that requires a password to save, or pass the password from one sub to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with some complex functions, so I setup the following code to prevent some of my coworkers from making unintended changes and then saving the file.  Straightforward, and it works.  Unfortunately, I've outsmarted myself.

The same file requires occasional semi-manual updates that pull filename information from our network drives.  I wrote a macro that accomplishes this.  It runs when the user clicks on a button.  [It's semi-manual because we work on different continents and while that update takes 90 seconds in France, it takes 30 minutes in the US.]  That also works.

My problem is that I want everyone to be able to run the macro update and then allow the file to autosave afterwards, but I don't want to give out the password to everyone in the group.  Currently, the update macro stalls when it hits the "beforesave" code.  Is there a way to either

1. bypass this password request when running the save from the update macro, or
2. put the password into the update macro in a way that the "beforesave" code will recognize and accept it

Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

   Dim Password As String Dim EnteredPassword As String

   Password = "NOTMYACTUALPASSWORD" 
   EnteredPassword = InputBox("Enter password to save changes") 

   If EnteredPassword <> Password Then 
       Cancel = True 
       MsgBox ("Password incorrect, file not saved") 
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you take a look at using the `SaveAsUI` value?

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell Excel to skip the `BeforeSave` block, but you can make your code exit before the code that stops saving.

```
' In a new module
Public Update_Active As Boolean ' defaults to False when not set

' At the end of your update macro before save is called
Update_Enable = True

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

   If Update_Active Then
      Update_Active = False
      Exit Sub
   End If

   Dim Password As String Dim EnteredPassword As String

   Password = "NOTMYACTUALPASSWORD" 
   EnteredPassword = InputBox("Enter password to save changes") 

   If EnteredPassword <> Password Then 
       Cancel = True 
       MsgBox ("Password incorrect, file not saved") 
   End If

End Sub
```